# Is Storm badly suited for batch learning?

Tags: machine-learning, streaming, batch-processing, apache-storm

From various sources on the net, I understand that Storm has some machine learning capabilities (via Samoa for example) but is it *always* for online learning? Corollary question: am I wrong if I say that Storm is not suited for the more classical batch learning because of the inherent iterative nature of this kind of processing?
Thank you for clarifying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why it is for online learning is because is a solution to process data one by one, that you can scale up by setting up some paralelization (more working processes and nodes).

You typically do batch learning to build or train models with historical data, but for that processing the data one by one is not your best option. Since you may need to process months of data, you want to batch it to optimize the process. This is where other solutions like spark come in place.